# KVM Win 7 Pro + RH virtio net driver

Tags: linux, debian, windows-7, kvm-virtualization, virtio

Host: Debian 7.2 x64.

Guest Win 7 Pro 32-bit. Virtio disk drivers work flawlessly, but there's a problem with virtio net (netkvm something) drivers. Virtio drivers come from `virtio-win-0.1-74.iso`.

This network card works perfectly in win7 guest:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:ea:39:d5'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

This one doesn't:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:70:c9:64'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Obviously I have installed the drivers from ISO, they show up in Device Manager as working without a problem. The card "just" does not seem to communicate with host - e.g. it does not show up in `arp -n` output on host.

I'm using Linux guests on the same host with virtio too and they just work, so can it be related to host config?

How can I fix that?

Comment: Review the network configuration within the guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pure trial & error I have found that virtio eth cards work if I disable `TCP Checksum Offload` and `UDP Checksum Offload` in eth card config (guest OS: Win 7 Pro SP1 32-bit).