# Can't install VirtIO Network Adapter in Win 7 Guest

Tags: windows-7, proxmox

I am playing around with different hypervisors, and I'm on to Proxmox VE. I setup an old server to test it out on, and installed Windows 7 as my first VM, using `virtio` drivers for everything - networking, disk controller, etc. I followed the recommendations from [this page](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_7_guest_best_practices) on the Proxmox Wiki, and downloaded the latest ISO using `wget` from `https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/stable-virtio/virtio-win.iso`.

I then tried to let Windows automatically search the CD for the drivers, and everything is installed. My issue is that the Network Adapter is showing a Code 10, cannot start, shown below:

[image]

This is running on Debian Wheezy (the version the Proxmox ISO had included), with a Windows 7 x86 guest. I have even tried shutting down the VM, and changing the MAC address, but no change. I have also tried disabling the `TCP/UDP Checksum Offload` options as suggested in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/565509/23513) to a similar issue. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers repeatedly, restarting in between. Settings below:

[image]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943104

Comment: Upper/Lower Filters doesn't exist in this machine. Tried the 'Fix It' app, but it just claimed the driver needed to be reinstalled - no change

Comment: Then why don't you do that?

Comment: I did... About 10 times. Sorry, I thought I posted that in the question, apparently not yet

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the current [stable-virtio 0.1.96](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/archive-virtio/virtio-win-0.1.96/).

[latest-virtio](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/latest-virtio/) 0.1.105 works for me.